# simple form in angularjs php

Tags: php, forms, angularjs

My form code is

```
      <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" action="form.php" method="POST">
      Name: <input name="input" ng-model="userName" name="name" required placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
      Email: <input name="email" ng-model="userEmail" name="email" required placeholder="Enter Email"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
       <tt>userType = {{userName}}</tt><br>
       <tt>userEmail = {{userEmail}}</tt><br>
      </form>
```

My script is

```
<script >
    function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.userName = '';
  $scope.userEmail = '';
}
</script>
```

form.php code is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo $name."<br>";
        echo $email."<br>";
    }
```

how to pass form value to php , any idea

Comment: which form value eaxctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would prefer to keep my model inside an object:

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fC1GikCS0v1tDVTG37vZ?p=preview

**controller**

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.user = {
    name : '',
    email: ''
  };

  $scope.submit = function(user){    

     $http.post('/form.php', user);

  }
}
```

**html**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="submit(user)">

  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"><br>
  Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in ur code above u used name tag twice..
thats y in php code it was not picking up the data.